# OS X Mountain Lion - Cannot Select Disk to Install on when using VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-mountain-lion

I want to install OS X Mountain Lion in VirtualBox, but I am having a problem: every time I run the install, I can't get past the "Select a Disk to Install" screen. I always hangs like this.

[image: "Select a Disk to Install" Screen Hangs]

What's the problem? I am running Windows 8.1 Pro x64 as the host, and have VirtualBox 4.3.4. When the installer utility loaded, I selected the "Reinstall OS X" option.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is that you have a virtual disk but still don't have any partition on it (disk in terms of Windows filesystem).
To fix that do the following:

1. Go to menu Install OS X Mountain Lion -> Quit Instal OS X.
2. Select Disk Utility
3. Select your disk on the left side. If you can't find the disk, click on the button near the top left, then select the "Show all disks" option.
4. Select erase tab on the right side
5. Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
6. Name: Give it a name
7. Click erase. This will create a partition on your disk drive
8. Quit Disk Utility and continue with installation as you did.

Comment: In recent versions Disk Utility is available via menu bar (no need to quit install).

Comment: If you can't see all your disks there, there's a hidden menu button at the top left, from there select "Show all disks" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks but there are two issues for me with this method: 1. I want to keep all files - so don't really want to erase. 2. Even if I want to erase, the `erase disk` button is grayed out so I cannot do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3768495 found any solution?